# Parsing XML with xpath in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm using the following code to check on a condition based on value of an xpath. Not all XMLs I've has this xpath. I want to identify which XML has this xpath, and which one don't. I'm using "from lxml import etree"

Sample XML - A:

```
<x>
  <a>
     <b>30</b>
  </a>
</x>
```

Sample XML - B:

```
<x>
  <a>
     <c>20</c>
  </a>
</x>
```

Code:

```
check_id = tree.xpath("a/b")
if check_id != None:
    is_id = True
else:
    is_id = False
```

I want to print 'True' for XML A and 'False' for XML B. But I'm getting this for both:

```
[] True
```

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: I'm using "from lxml import etree"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
check_id = tree.xpath("//*/a/b")
```